# php preg_match find url

Tags: php, url, split, preg-match

I can get a full page source. It similer like this:

```
&url240=http://cs518313v4.vk.me/u187298368/videos/c733ac6e5c.240.mp4&url360=http://cs518313v4.vk.me/u187298368/videos/c733ac6e5c.360.mp4&jpg=http://cs518313v4.vk.me/u187298368/video/l_292f9ac5.jpg&
```

How can I get only url 240 link http://cs518313v4.vk.me/u187298368/videos/c733ac6e5c.240.mp4 and url 360 link http://cs518313v4.vk.me/u187298368/videos/c733ac6e5c.360.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using preg_match:

```
$string = '&url240=http://cs518313v4.vk.me/u187298368/videos/c733ac6e5c.240.mp4&url360=http://cs518313v4.vk.me/u187298368/videos/c733ac6e5c.360.mp4&jpg=http://cs518313v4.vk.me/u187298368/video/l_292f9ac5.jpg&';
preg_match("/&url240=(.*?)&/", $string, $A);
preg_match("/&url360=(.*?)&/", $string, $B);

$urla = $A[1]; // url 240
$urlb = $B[1]; // url 360
```

Not sure it's the best way, though, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach is just using [**parse_str**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function to, well, parse a string:

```
$arr = [];
parse_str($url, $arr);
echo $arr['url240'];
echo $arr['url360'];
```

The point is, this task is already solved by PHP developers, and solution IS tested. Makes little sense inventing your own solution instead.

Comment: I cant use it. My code is 
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('http://localhost/test.html');
//get full source
//echo ($page);

?>
<textarea style="margin: 2px; width: 1008px; height: 310px;"><?php echo $page; ?></textarea>

Answer (score 0):

If that's your use case, try:

```
$search="url240";
preg_match("/$search=([^&]*)&/",$page,$matches);
$url240=$matches[1];
```

But this is expecting

1. An ampersand at the end of every URL
2. No individual URL containing query params like "?p1=v1&p2=v2".

From your source it looks like the urls are delimited by ampersands, as if they were URL query parameters. Maybe something like (&|\s) to catch that last URL that won't be followed by an ampersand. It all depends on the data you're expecting.